# What is the step by step mechanism for charge to accumulate on the capacitors of this circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, capacitance

[image]

In this circuit, what will initiate the charge to flow from the batteries to the capacitors? I would like to know how is sufficient potential difference created in this circuit to allow for the required charges to accumulate on the capacitors.

Comment: Welcome! Is this homework? What have you tried so far?

Comment: At least one of those capacitors is reverse polarized and won't survive.

Comment: @winny , I assumed charges on the capacitors when the circuit has reached equilibrium, and then used kirchoffs voltage law to form equations and find the charges and then used that to find the potential difference between a and b which is what the question had asked to do, but I wanted to know about the step by step inner mechanism by which we reach to these final charges on the capacitors in equilibrium.

Comment: @Hearth The asymmetrical symbol can be used to indicate outer foil or suchlike; I would not assume these are polarized unless indicated with a plus, or the type defined in supporting text or BOM.

Answer (score 2):

An ideal capacitor has an internal resistance of 0Ohms.  There is no "step by step" mechanism to connect ideal capacitors to ideal voltage sources: whatever you do will explode into non-ideal physics, like oscillation emitting energy through electromagnetic fields, internal resistances of voltage sources and capacitors and connections eating up energy and slowing the process and so on.

With that kind of circuitry, all you can do is stipulate that you start with zero charge on all capacitors and end with the given point to point voltages, set up the respective voltage/charge equations and solve.  The "step by step", in contrast, is completely unspecifiable and depends on non-ideal characteristics of the components.

The voltage settling on b as compared to a will clearly be larger than 6V and smaller than 24V.  That means that at least the 4µF capacitor will be reverse-charged.  So you better use an unpolarized or bipolar (like those used in passive frequency crossovers) capacitor for this one.  Possibly also for the 2µF capacitor.

Comment: this diagram is from a part of a question that asked to find the potential difference between a and b, I assumed some charges on the capacitors when the circuit has reached equilibrium, and then used kirchoffs voltage law, and formed equations to solve the charges and then used that to find the potential difference between a and b,... Are you also saying that this is the best we can do, and the mechanism of how we end up with these charges on the capacitors is complicated and involves non ideal physics?

Comment: @AdityaMukherjee Yes, with those idealized components, you can do a before/after analysis but there is no continuous process leading from one to the other that would not quantitatively depend on parasitic entities not in the circuit diagram.  Even the simpler case of one voltage source connected with one capacitor has no self-consistent process between before/after.

Comment: but the charging of a single capacitor connected to a single voltage source with a resistance in between, can be explained nicely by equations.

Comment: @AdityaMukherjee "but"?  I didn't claim that all circuits involving capacitors don't have time-based solutions.

Comment: @AdityaMukherjee *but* you don't have a resistance in-between in this circuit. Remember that circuit analysis is quite an abstract process, and the components represent coefficients in a matrix (or in any equivalent manner). The components don't necessarily represent anything physically possible! **Circuit analysis done at the level you show is the schematic as a stand-in for numbers and matrix structure** - a most abstract process. A physical circuit will have all sorts of interesting parasitics and nonlinearities added into it.

Comment: @AdityaMukherjee There are no steps, since the circuit only "does something" i.e. changes state during an infinitesimal period of time after t=0. That means that the only way to determine its behavior is to take a limit as t->0+. There's no physical counterpart to that. There's just one step: taking the limit itself.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica It's not just that things happen in an "infinitesimal period of time", because if they did, physics would hold up.  But we don't even get from one state to the other while preserving energy: the voltage source spent U·Q in energy while the capacitor received U·Q/2 in energy and there is no circuit element that could account for the difference.  Regardless of how fast or slow the process happens.  Some ideal components are unfit for mating without some mitigating reality in between, even if the mating time is infinitesimally small.

Answer (score 0):

This simulation computes and plots the processes in the circuit of your drawing:

[image: polcaps]

There are no parasitics or internal resistances in the circuit of this simulation: in fact, there are no resistances except for the resistance in the model of a diode. Why the diode is here? As other posters noted, in this circuit the voltage across some polarized capacitors can become reversed, i.e., the potential of the capacitor's plus (+) terminal can become lower than the potential of the minus terminal. Polarized capacitors can be destroyed by reverse voltage, but also can withstand it for short periods if the absolute value of this voltage is less than 1 V.

The diode is used to simulate the valve effect, the current through the capacitor under reverse voltage. The use of diode for modeling the valve effect raises questions about what diode parameters (saturation current, internal resistance) should be used. As it turns out (and you can verify this claim by varying the component parameters and running the simulation), the simulation graphs depend on these parameters only weakly. Most decisive is that the reverse voltage generates the current and this current grows exponentially with increasing reverse voltage.

In addition to the diode modeling of valve effect, I'm introducing the rise time of voltage source pulses. If there is no resistance, the instantaneous switching of voltage in capacitor networks generates infinite currents. Non-zero rise time solves two problems: with sufficient duration, it eliminates the dependance on unknown parameters (capacitor ESR, voltage source internal resistance) and helps manage the timing of switching power on the circuit. Notice also the sign in the graph I(C3)-I(D3): the current directions are opposite, so the total current through a simulated polarized capacitor C3+D3 is the difference of I(C3) and I(D3) values. Also, I do not use diodes to model the behavior of C1 and C2, as these two never experience reverse voltage in this circuit. For other tests, you can add D1 and D2 to the simulation.

As a result, with a quite reasonable 10ms of switching power rise time we have transient currents less than 10mA, which polarized capacitors typically tolerate.

The simulation plot shows that the only capacitor suffering reverse voltage is C3, and this reverse voltage is nearly infinitesimal, on the order of millivolt.

While examining this simulation, you see a `mechanism of accumulating charges on the capacitors` of your circuit and a proof that, under certain conditions (restricted switch-on rise time), your capacitors (rated for the voltages you use) survive this test.

Answer (score 0):

The question is designed to be answered by using superposition. Those are the steps for determining the charge. With ideal components the currents are all Dirac impulses (zero width, infinite magnitude, finite area) and the charge is deposited instantly, there are no time steps.

The charge Q = CV on C1, C2, C3 is easy to find for V1=V1, V2=0, V3=0, then the analysis is repeated for V1=0, V2=V2, V3=0 and V1=0, V2=0, V3=0. The charge deposited on C1 with all of the independent voltage sources active is the sum of the charge deposited when each source is the only one that is active.

For this problem a student would draw the equivalent circuit for each case. They’re all a battery and 2 capacitors in series where the second capacitor happens to be 2 capacitors in parallel. The student should find a single equivalent capacitor to get the total charge moved by the voltage source, then the voltage at the capacitor to capacitor junction. Most quickly see that they can they just divide the charge proportionally between the parallel caps.

For example, with only the 6v source active, the 2uF in parallel with 1uF is 3uF and 3uF in series with 4uF is 12/7 uF, Q1 = 12/7 * 6 μC = 72/7μC. The charge on C2 and C3 is divided proportionally, 144/21 μC on C2 and 72/21 μC on C3.

This instructor’s class would have gotten more out of their answers if 1uF 24v 2uF 12v and 3uF 8v had been chosen. The way it’s written the fractions above will all be written as meaningless decimal equivalents and the final answer is inelegant. An opportunity to develop the student’s intuitive insight into charge transfer has been missed. It will be more difficult to get them to analyze the voltage doubler, tripler, etc. systematically.